# PHP: exec weirdness

Tags: php, console, exec

This is my code:

```
        $command = 'path to some script';
        echo "Running command:\n $command ";
        $result = array ();
        exec ($command, $result);
```

Which results in the following:

Running command:
[here go some warning printed by the command itself]
path to some script

I.e. the error output of the script, is somehow inserted in the middle (!) of an echo command preceding it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This will be down to buffered vs non-buffered io. The error output will be stderror, and the other will be stdout. Stdout is generally buffered - so if you were to force it to flush before running the script you would get the result you want.

Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: However, I don't understand how the an unbuffered stuff enters *in the middle* of one buffered string!

Answer (score 1):

This is because `exec` does not capture standard error (*stderr*), per example:

```
exec ('/bin/echo foo > /dev/stderr', $result);
```

Will output `foo`, even though `exec` shouldn't output anything. You can force it to by doing:

```
exec ($command.' 2>&1', $result);
```

The reason it appears in the middle is probably because of output buffering (as @Danny explained above). The output buffer may exhaust before the end of command and therefore is flushed automatically, and a new one is started. Hence the error appearing in the middle.